# Changing Wordpress Gallery Structure

Tags: wordpress, gallery, structure

I have read through many posts and articles about styling a Wordpress Gallery, but I would like to change the structure.  Below is an example of a normal gallery code.  I want to remove the `<dl> <dt> <br>` and replace them with my own elements.  Any idea where I can do this in the Wordpress file structure?

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-1 gallery-columns-1 gallery-size-thumbnail">
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon">
    <a href="http://mydomain.com/2012/01/hello-world/dsc_0003/" title="DSC_0003"><img width="376" height="250" src="http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/DSC_0003-376x250.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="DSC_0003" title="DSC_0003"></a>
</dt>
</dl>
<br style="clear: both">
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon">
    <a href="http://mydomain.com/2012/01/hello-world/dsc_0003/" title="DSC_0003"><img width="376" height="250" src="http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/DSC_0003-376x250.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="DSC_0003" title="DSC_0003"></a>
</dt>
</dl>
<br style="clear: both">
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one did want to further customize the default post gallery you can add a [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to post_gallery to produce your own output. if the post_gallery filter returns anything, the default gallery output will be ignored. as a starting point, look at the gallery shortcode function, which is located in /wp-includes/media.php. it uses [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post) to fetch attachments and output them. you could copy that function entirely into your functions.php file and change the name and use that as your filter.

Comment: Sounds good.  I may just edit the /wp-includes/media.php file directly.  If I did choose to copy over the shortcode to functions.php where in that file would I place it?  Just at the top?

Comment: yes you can duplicate it with duplicate function `gallery_shortcode()` `add_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');` and rename it and also exclude the section `if ( is_feed() ) {
  $output = "\n";
  foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
   $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
  return $output;
 }` when you copy it to function.php